# Load 2 dimensional array in Object into devexpress gridcontrol

Tags: c#, reflection, devexpress

I'm calling a Matlab function from a c# .net application.  The following code calls the function which returns a two dimensional array containing strings and doubles.

```
object result = null;

matlab.Feval("matlabTest", 1, out result);
```

If I hover over `result` when debugging I can see that `result` which is an `{object[1]}` is a proper two-dimensional array containing `{object[53,13]}` of strings and doubles.  How can the object `result` be displayed in a DevExpress `GridControl`?

Comment: Take a look at [«How to bind the XtraGrid to a two-dimensional array»](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1075) example.

Comment: Please post your binding code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to two-dimensional arrays is not specific for WinForms. If you use a standard DataGridView, you won't get your data either. You need a list. So, convert your array to a list to display data:

```
object[,] result = new object[10, 5];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result[i, 0] = (double)i;
    result[i, 1] = "test";
    result[i, 2] = (double)i;
    result[i, 3] = "test";
    result[i, 4] = (double)i;
}
List<object> list = new List<object>();
for(int i = 0; i < result.GetLength(0); i++) {
    list.Add(new { Field1 = result[i, 0], Field2 = result[i, 1], Field3 = result[i, 2], Field4 = result[i, 3], Field5 = result[i, 4] });
}
gridControl1.DataSource = list;
```

[image]

Comment: When using this code I get the message: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetLength' and no extension method 'GetLength' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.  Also, result[i,0] does not compile with the message, "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'."

Comment: Obviously, you don't cast the object that is returned by your code to object[,]

Answer (score 0):

Refer documentation example: [How to bind the XtraGrid to a two-dimensional array](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1075)

> The XtraGrid doesn't natively support this kind of datasource.
>   However, you can create a wrapper class, which implements the
>   necessary interfaces and provides access to array data via them. In
>   this example, we create a generic wrapper for 2-dimensional arrays and
>   implement essential members of IList and ITypedList interfaces.

As @Gosha_Fighen shown you an example which is also converting that 2-d array to the XtraGrid supported data source. You must convert this array to IList or Data table to bind it with the grid control.

In the specified example we pass array and it it will get converted to the type of IList.

Hope this help